# Converting a date to a carbon instance from query results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I was recently adding some functionality to a moderation queue that I have. Instead of querying one table, Questionnaire, it is now querying Users to so that I can grab their username.

My previous query was just

```
$questionnaire = Questionnaire::all();
```

And then when I accessed this on the page I could format it like so:

```
{{ $questionnaire->created_at->format('F d, Y h:ia') }}
```

This is how my new query looks in my controller:

```
public function moderate()
    {
        $questionnaires = DB::table('users')
                        ->join('questionnaire', 'users.id', '=', 'questionnaire.memberid')
                        ->select('users.username', 'questionnaire.*')
                        ->get();
        return view('questionnaire.moderate', ['questionnaires' => $questionnaires]);
    }
```

However when I try to access the `created_at` date on the page now I get a `Call to a member function format() on a non-object` error. My digging leads me to believe this is because the date isn't converted to a carbon instance.

However all the documentation on Carbon is for when you're just pulling the date and I'm struggling to figure out how to convert it after I get the query results so that I can still access it on the page.

Can anyone hel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Carbon API](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation), you can create a Carbon instance like so:

```
$myDate = new Carbon($questionnaire->created_at);
```

And then just format it the way you want:

```
{{ $myDate->format('F d, Y h:ia') }}
```

It may not be exactly what you want, but it'll work.

P.S: your Questionnaire model has the created_at field inside the $dates attribute? I thought that was just enough, even accessing the data the way you are doing it now.

Comment: Where would I set the $myDate then, inside the view? The query pulls a bunch of records that I then use in a foreach loop to display them on the page.

Comment: If you wanna do it inside your view, you can do it like so: {{ (new Carbon\Carbon($questionnaire->created_at))->format('F d, Y h:ia') }} instead of {{ $questionnaire->created_at->format('F d, Y h:ia') }}

Answer (score 1):

Even though the accepted answer resolves the original question "Converting a date to a carbon instance", a better solution for the system, would have been to get a Carbon datetime object every time you access the column. To achieve that,

1) If it's a custom column, be sure it is listed in protected `$dates` property of the model you are accessing from, as mentioned here https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators.

2) If its a default `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps then make sure the public `$timestamps` property of the model is set to true.

After that you can easily retrieve the column as a Carbon datetime object anywhere like

```
{{ $questionnaire->created_at->format('F d, Y h:ia') }}
```

and not have to convert the column to datetime on every other query.

In your particular case, it looks like the `Questionnaire` model is set properly, hence you were able to access the column as a datetime object. So I think the following code should work in your case:

```
$questionnaires = Questionnaire::select('users.username', 'questionnaire.*')
                        ->join('users', 'questionnaire.memberid', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->get();
```